# In Silverlight, how do you find out whether the code is running in the UI thread or not?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, multithreading

Basically I need to know whether I need to can Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or if it's not needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`Dispatcher.CheckAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess%28VS.95%29.aspx) method. It returns true if you're on the same thread as the UI dispatcher, and false otherwise

Comment: Is there any static entry point to get the Dispatcher? AFAIK I need a UI element to grab hold of the Dispatcher.

Comment: There is a static entry point (`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`), but it will return the dispatcher for the current thread, not the UI thread... If you want the UI thread, you can use `Application.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher`

Comment: You could also do Deployment.Current.Dispatcher