# Detect if code is running on background thread or UI (Dispatcher) thread

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, dispatcher

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that uses the [Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244535/thread-affinity-of-ui-controls-in-windows-phone-7) to make sure code gets run on the UI thread, but sometimes I need to know which thread the method was called on.

How can I detect if a method is called from the UI thread or from a background thread? In Silverlight you would use [Dispatcher.CheckAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041949/in-silverlight-how-do-you-find-out-whether-the-code-is-running-in-the-ui-thread), but that is not available on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Here is a helpful utility class if anyone else needs to detect background/foreground threads among other things: http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3bd7fb2d5eb2#WP7_Barcode_Library%2fOther%2fWP7Utilities.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CheckAccess is there, it just doesn't show in intellisense. Code it and you'll see it compiles/runs.

Comment: Well would you look at that! I wonder why it doesn't show up in intellisense or the Object browser. Thanks!

Comment: You can also get and set thread names using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name - personally, I name important threads for easier debugging.